# Fancybox won't pop into Fancybox window

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to make the image "pop" as well, but nothing is working. Here is the code I have inserted between the Head tags:

"

```
<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

<!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick : true,

            openEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding: 0,

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                overlay : null
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
         */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });


        /*
         *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
         */

        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
        */
        $('.fancybox-media')
            .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                arrows : false,
                helpers : {
                    media : {},
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });

        /*
         *  Open manually
         */

        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'iframe.html',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : '1_b.jpg',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : '2_b.jpg',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    });
</script>
```

"

And this is the sample code I have for the image that is meant to pop into a Fancybox window, inserted somewhere inside the Body tag:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/thumbnail_chry_bw.png" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="images/thumbnail_chry_bw.png" alt="" /></a>
```

They are sourced right in the sense that the two folders containing the jquery files (lib) and (source) are located in the same folder as the HTML file containing the code mentioned here. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong as web development is not my forte. But yes, pretty much what I have is the `<script>` codes inside the Head tags and the image links inside the Body tag.

Comment: are you trying something like this http://jsfiddle.net/bG4gR/1166/? if yes then your code is working fine.

Comment: u there @KatherineV? did this fiddle work for you?

Comment: Make sure the paths to your fancybox css and js files are correct